# Curl Error when trying to POST to AWS endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, post, parse-platform

I got

error: `{"error":"Unexpected token ‘"}`

with the `curl` `command` below.

What gives?

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id:SomeID" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d ‘{“number”:"3016524500"}’ \
http://somedomain.com/parse/functions/testFunction
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're using different characters than the actual ' and " characters.  Try replacing ” with " and ‘ with '.

Comment: Yup!  Thanks for the answer.   the single quotes indeed ' ' changed, probably during cut and paste from browser and text editor.